# C++ static cast and compilation

Tags: c++

I'm making some tests with simple cast and I would like to know if everything is correct. I would like to cast a `vector` of `unsigned int` to an array of `unsigned char`/`unsigned short` (to send Geometry data to GPU). The goal is to get all geometry's attributes and create an interleaved array with his attributes (position, colors, normals, texture's uvs, …).

Everything works when I show the result in console, but I'm afraid of a result with a different architecture/different compiler.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> tests;
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    tests.push_back(i+1);

// With Uint8
unsigned char* tests2 = (unsigned char*)(tests.data());
unsigned char k = 0;
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++, k += sizeof(unsigned int) )
      std::cout << (int) *(tests2 + k) << std::endl;

// With Ushort
unsigned short* tests3 = (unsigned short*)(tests.data());
unsigned short l= 0;
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++, l += sizeof(unsigned int) )
     std::cout << (int) *(tests3 + l) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Endianness will rear up on this if you expect output to be universally equivalent on all platforms. It won't be on BE vs LE platforms. Nor is it clear *why* this is being done in the first place, but it doesn't really matter much regarding the first concern.

Comment: I don't understand how this is representative of an actual situation. Surly you're not going to be passing an int array to the GPU where it'll be interpreted as a short array.

Comment: It's totally wrong. tests2 is a pointer to char pointing to an array of uint. adding to a pointer of char adds a numerical 1 to the address; it still points to the same int, just one byte advanced. Casting doesn't work the way you think, I think.

Comment: To be more productive: You'll need a new target array and copy test's elements over. Preferably use another vector and some std copy algorithm, if that allows you to specify the narrowing conversion for each element; otherwise just do it manually.

Comment: For what meaning of "works"?  The second loop has undefined behavior; for the first, it is unspecified (by the standard, at least) what will be output.